# How do I add content to the center of the page without pushing the contents of my left sidenav down?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently building a website but I've been having troubles with arranging the content. I'd like to add content to the center of the page, inline with the music tab in the left sidenav. Everytime I add something to the center, it pushes everything downwards.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
  <title>Rob's Music</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Biryani' rel='stylesheet'>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/c37e8e0ff9.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      background-color: #f8f5ef;
    }
    .navbar-default {
      background-color: #f8f5ef;
      border-color: #f8f5ef;
      color: #f8f5ef;
    }
    [class^="btn-"],
    [class*="btn-"] {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: #f8f5ef;
      float: right;
      padding-top: 1%;
    }
    [class^="reverb-nation"],
    [class*="reverb-nation"] {
      background-position: right;
      height: 16px;
      width: 16px;
      padding-top: 2.5%;
    }
    [class^="navbar-brand"],
    [class*="navbar-brand"] {
      padding-left: 0%;
      font-size: 450%;
      padding-top: 2.5%;
    }
    #home {
      font-size: 200%;
      color: #000000;
    }
    #home:hover {
      font-size: 200%;
      color: #000000;
    }
    #music {
      font-size: 200%;
      color: #000000;
    }
    #music:hover {
      font-size: 200%;
      color: #000000;
    }
    .carousel-inner > .item > img,
    .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
    }
    #content {
      font-size: 100%;
      padding-left: 0%;
      width: 600%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navbar -->




  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 class="navbar-brand">My Band</h1>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <a class="btn btn-default" href="">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>
      </a>
      <a class="btn btn-default" href="">
        <i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a>
      <a class="btn btn-default" href="">
        <img src="../1484039391_ReverbNationsm.png" class="reverb-nation"></img>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Title and links to other pages -->
  <div class="container-fluid">


    <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
      <div class="hover-icon">
        <br></br>
        <div class="row">
          <a id="home" href="">Home</a>

          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <a id="music" href="music.html">Music</a>
          </div <div class="col-sm-6">
          <h2>News</h2>
          <p class="well" id="content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus magna ut se
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="row">
        <h3>News</h3>
        <h3>Events</h3>
        <h3>Photos</h3>
        <h3>Videos</h3>
        <h3>About</h3>
        <h3>Contact</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>


  <br></br>
  <br></br>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: actually which part do you want to center?

Comment: follow this link might help u -> https://youtu.be/hIG-fZ2042k

Comment: I'm trying to center the <h2>News</h2> and the <p class="well" id="content"> without it shifting everything in my sidenav downwards.